# Show that $\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous but not Lipschitz.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I'm having problems proving the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous, but not a Lipschitz function on the interval $(0,\infty)$. If I assume U.C , I can show it's not Lipschitz. However, I'm having problems showing it's U.C on that interval.

Answer (score 2):

On the closed interval $[0,1]$, and hence on $(0,1]$, we have uniform continuity because of continuity. On $[1,\infty)$ we have uniform continuity because the derivative is bounded.

Comment: Then what if I pick $x\in (0,1]$ and $y\in [1,\infty)$ so that $|x-y|<\delta$?

Comment: Good question. For uniform continuity, if we want $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\lt \epsilon$, where $x$ and $y$ straddle $1$, we use the boundedness of the derivative in $[0.9,1.1]$.